# Laravel: TokenMismatchException after uploading large video file

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, file-upload

I already set the php.ini (nginx)

> upload_max_size = 100MB
>
> post_max_size = 200mb

I'm trying to upload a 15mb video to my program. At first i got this error.

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:

So I added the '/lesson/store' in the exception from VerifyCSRFToken middleware.

Here's the shortcode highlighting the video input:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="video">Video:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">       

            <input class="form-control" type="file" accept="video/*" name="video" id="video" required>

        </div>
     </div>
```

And here's the whole form code:

```
<form method="{{$method}}" action="{{url('')}}{{$action}}" class="form-horizontal"  runat="server"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

{{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="title">Title:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title"  placeholder="Enter title" required value="{{ $lesson->title or '' }}">
        </div>
     </div> 
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="description">Description:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description">{{ $lesson->description or '' }}</textarea>        
        </div>
     </div> 
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="episode">Episode:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="episode" name="episode"  placeholder="" required value="{{ $lesson->episode or '' }}">
        </div>
     </div> 
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="video">Video:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">

           @if( !empty( $lesson->video ) )
           <input class="form-control" type="file" accept="video/*" name="video" id="video">
           <div class="video">
            <video width="100%" style="height:200px" controls>
              <source src="{{url('uploads/courses/' . $lesson['course_id']. '/' . $lesson['video'])}}" type="video/mp4">      
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
           </div>  
           @else
            <input class="form-control" type="file" accept="video/*" name="video" id="video" required>
           @endif
        </div>
     </div> 

     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="submit" value="{{$button}}" class="btn btn-success">
            <a href="{{ url()->previous() }}" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
        </div>
     </div>


</form>
```

Then I tried to upload again and I received a validation errors says:

> The video field is required

Because I have this in my code:

```
 $this->validate($request, [
   'video' => 'required|mimetypes:video/avi,video/mpeg,video/quicktime,video/mp4|max:40000'
      ]);
```

I really don't know how to fix this thing.

Update: I uploaded 5mb video and I got this validation error:

> The video failed to upload.

Comment: Show us your code within `form` when you add video!

Comment: In addition to php.ini , did you also increase upload size on nginx? (Check out https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/csrf-mismatch-with-multipartform-data )

Comment: I just did that still got the tokenmismatch error.

Comment: is it occurring even if you upload small video? try and check

Comment: and do post your routes for this form, what is the url and method that is being replaced in the form?

Comment: @Exprator It don't occur on small video.

Comment: for create.blade.php i use url = /lesson/store 
for edit.blade.php i use url = /lesson/update

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden input field in your for verify csrf token as

```
<input type="text" name="_token" hidden/>
```

or

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Comment: I think {{ csrf_field() }} does that thing.

Comment: yeah both doing the same thing